# scope of the socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is it necessary to have the socket_lifetime_protector array.Does the **socket** gets destroyed outside the function scope.

```
var socket_lifetime_protector = []; // Is this necessary to protect the lifetime of socket

function createNewSocket(username)
{
    var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000');

    socket_lifetime_protector.push(socket); // Is this required

    socket.on('some_signal', function() {...});
}
```

Comment: well...your socket object won't be accessible outside the scope of the `createNewSocket` function otherwise...so it makes sense to capture it. However, if you plan on defining all of your socket logic within that scope, it probably isn't necessary. It will ultimately depend on how you want to further architect your solution.

Comment: @JordanForeman I dont want to access sockets outside. All the logic is within the **createNewSocket** function. But still how does the scope gets retained. As per the syntax of javascript, the scope of the object is valid only inside the function, is that correct?

Comment: correct - although it will also be available within any function (anonymous or otherwise) that you declare within the scope of `createNewSocket`; so in your last line (typo btw), the anonymous function you will write as a callback to `socket.on('some_signal', function(){..});` will have access to the socket object, because it has access to the scope of its "parent" - which in this case is `createNewSocket`

Comment: @JordanForeman Lets say the function **createNewSocket();** is called and after the call end's does all the **sockets** created within the function will be destroyed (even if the anonymous functions within the **createNewSocket** is holding the reference of socket. It should not matter because the anonymous function is withing the scope of the **createNewSocket** function as per my understanding) ?.

Comment: No, it won't be destroyed. It will just exist in the state that it was left in at the end of execution of `createNewSocket()` - listening for the signals you've defined and responding accordingly. You won't be able to access it dynamically in any way, but we've already established that that isn't a concern. Are you running into an issue when you don't persist it yourself? I suppose I could be off base here, but I'm pretty sure GC will leave the socket object alone until you restart your application

Comment: @JordanForeman There is no issue if i don't persist the connection. Just curious what makes GC not destroy the socket object. Is it guaranteed ?.